# Get dynamic text from selected object - (by ID and "active" class) - jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**My main mission:** Is to get the text of the next and the previous objects to the chosen object - To display the image (and its titles) Previous & Next.

**Before that I have a problem:** to get text of a selected object, from an index to a variable.

**The problem:** Every time I pick a random object, the variable does not change but the text is added to the existing text in the index.

I made a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mzQAa/5/), would appreciate your help.

```
$(document).ready(function hintProject(){
   $('#nextProject, #prevProject').click(function(){

        subtitle = null;
        subtitle = $('#client-sub.active').justtext();
        $('#next_target_title').text(subtitle);

        alert (' text::: ' + subtitle );       
    });
});
```

Comment: `justtext`? what is it?

Comment: I think you have to explain your problem a bit better.

Comment: Is there a reason why you declare `hintProject`inside a `$(document).ready` function?

Comment: justtext it's a function - Get The Text Of Element Without Child Element [link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element/) @gdoron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like jQuery simply can't find the objects you're specifying. I don't think the problem is with the snippet in the question. I think the problem is with your document ready function.

To debug, try simplifying your problem by cutting out all of the additional complexity of the setup script and just set up an HTML page that is in the state you want. It's much easier to understand 1 problem than 2 or more.

Also, try simplifying how you're specifying an active item: a single class on the portfolio item would make your life easier. Then you can specify css and such based on the parent instead of adding multiple classes to multiple things inside the each portfolio item.